# Changing ajax to fade in and out

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using javascript and ajax to load in my content onto my div which is all working OK. But at the moment it's kind of static and a bit ugly.

I am trying to get it to fade in and out so when a new tab is clicked the previous one will fade out then the new one will fade in.

I have found the syntax to use is `$(selector).fadeIn(speed,callback)` but I can't figure out where to add this as everywhere I have read says add it after your click function but my code doesn't have that.

```
    var bustcachevar=1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
    var loadedobjects=""
    var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
    var bustcacheparameter=""

    function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
    var page_request = false
    document.getElementById(containerid).style.display = 'none';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
    try {
    page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    } 
    catch (e){
    try{
    page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    catch (e){}
    }
    }
    else
    return false
    page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    loadpage(page_request, containerid)
    }
    if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
    bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
    page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
    page_request.send(null)
    }

    function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
        if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)) {
            document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
            document.getElementById(containerid).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }


    function loadobjs(){
    if (!document.getElementById)
    return
    for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    var file=arguments[i]
    var fileref=""
    if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
    if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
    fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
    }
    else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
    fileref=document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
    }
    }
    if (fileref!=""){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
    loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using jQuery so `fadeIn` will not work unless you add it. If you do add jQuery, I would recommend using their ajax methods as well.

Comment: @jeroen I see so its only possible to use the fadein with jQuery and not javascript?

Comment: No, in the end jQuery is just javascript so you can do it in plain javascript as well. jQuery just makes it easier.

Comment: @jeroen Ok no problem would you be able to customize the code above to work? Or do you recommend I just change it to jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use JQuery to simply your AJAX code. It also has native functionality for doing fade in and out.

Here's an example

```
function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
   $.get(url, function(response) {
      $('#'+containerid).fadeOut('slow', function() { 
         $('#'+containerid).html($.trim(response));
         $('#'+containerid).fadeIn('slow'); 
      });
   });
}
```

The **function(response){}** part is the callback on the AJAX GET call, then the function() inside the **$('#'+containerid).fadeOut()** runs after the fade out is finished, which then calls the fadeIn().

Because the fade out, then filling in the new HTML, then fading in is in callbacks, it all happens in the right event order.

Comment: This seems like the best solution. How would I go about adding this to make it work with my code?

Comment: I've updated the code to be a function in the same format as your question. I simply change the AJAX call target to the **url** argument and the JQuery selector to use the **containerid** argument to manipulate the <div>. This should work as long as the **id** attribute equals the **containerid** argument. I remove the second parameters argument from my original code. This is an optional argument in $.get(), not sure if you still need to send parameters to your target page.

Answer (score 1):

For a javascript animation, I would include jQuery, but you could also use css3 if you don't mind leaving out a few older browsers.

Just add this to the css of the elements your are hiding / showing:

```
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

With this, when you change a css property like `display` from `block` to `none`, it will fade out.

**Edit:** To hide and show your element in js:

```
// you would put this in your click handler, so I guess in your ajaxpage function
document.getElementById(containerid).style.display = 'none';

// you would put this in the callback like
function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)) {
        document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
        document.getElementById(containerid).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: that sounds good but it doesn't seem to work when I add it into my css, not sure how to make it change to none when I click the button, think I may be better going down the jQuery root.

Comment: @Matt I see that you not changing any css but only replace the content of your element. To add an animation with css or jquery, you would need to change that anyway. For use with the code above, you would need to set `display: none` to `#containerid` when you click and set it to `display: block` again in the callback function of your ajax call.

Comment: I am a noob with javascript still is it possible for you to show me with a few comments?

Comment: I have don that now which when viewing in firebug it does seem to change from none to block but it is just flicking not fading I have added the css as well. I've updated the code above to what I have now

Comment: @Matt What does the css look like and what browser are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Fade in will only work when you're using a jQuery object.

```
var ele = document.querySelector('div');
ele.fadeIn(); // Fail
$(ele).fadeIn(); // Works
```

So if you have raw dom object (no jQuery), you can just run it through the `$` function and then you can use fadeIn.

## Update

---

Also, fadeIn does not have to be inside a click function, but that's just an example. You can run it (nearly) anywhere in your code.